# Multiple Drop Down with AutoComplete TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

Hello Guys I have Faced a problem with Multiple Drop Down the Drop Down has Auto Complete functionality when i Loop my Drop Down data with it it show me This Error.

> is not assignable to type 'AutocompleteProps<SelectControl, true,
> undefined, true, "div">'.   Types of property 'value' are
> incompatible.

i want drop down that show text in interface and dropdown Values in value

this is the example of drop down that i want
[Shot of Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2VUE.png)

and the Code Sandbox for the Dropdown is this

https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-dropddown-with-autoselect-tags-b19y9f?file=/src/App.tsx

i want Result From This Dropdown in string array such as ["1,2,3,4"]
Thanks in Advance